# Login failure after computer name change

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, login, microsoft-account

I'm using a Microsoft account for the login of my Windows 10 PC.
When I setup my PC I set it up the way that I didn't need to enter a password on boot up (can't remember how I did that).

Now I changed the computer name of my Windows 10 PC.
Since the name change my PC boots up and then tells me that the username or password was wrong.
On the login screen it shows two accounts. One is my Microsoft account and the active account it tries to prompt the login for looks like a local account (that account didn't exist before).
I'm unable to log into this strange new account.
If I click on the Microsoft account I can login.

I would like to remove this strange account and again be able to boot without login prompt. How to resolve that?

Answer (score 3):

I found the culprit.

Changing the computer name in the system settings didn't update the `DefaultDomainName` in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`.

Manually changing the `DefaultDomainName` to the same as my computer name solved the problem.

Not sure if this is a Windows 10 bug or expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

JoshRohlReplied on January 23, 2018
Same issue.

How I resolved it was by doing the following:

disable auto login under netplwiz
restart computer and choose the "forgot your password" option under your Microsoft account login (not the pseudo login with no picture)
changing the password
re-enabling automatic login under netplwiz
restart your computer to check
Hopefully this helps people out with a somewhat simple solution (even if it's a bit annoying).

thx to Josh you guys,other solutions didn't work out for me except for this one ...papa bless Josh Rohl wherever you are

Comment: This is a re-post of this [thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/changing-computer-name-screw-up-my-automatic-login/7416e79b-87ad-456e-8352-e3f3c4d9b03e?page=2). You must cite your source or your post will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Mine required a different setting. Changing the following registry key to the current computer name solved my problem:

```
HKLM\software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\DefaultLogonDomain
```